# Driver Issues connecting to Oracle 11g using MS OLE driver from SSIS

Tags: windows-7, ssis, oracle11g, driver

I am having driver issues trying to connect to an Oracle Database 11g in an SSIS SQL Server Integration Package.

In SSIS, I created a OLE Database Connection using the Native OLE DB\Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle. When I test the connection, the outcome is successful but I run into issues when I attempt to reference this Connection from an OLE DB Source task.

In the OLE DB Source task, I am able to see all of the tables but when I select one, I get the following error:

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0xC02020E8
Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Source [1]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Unspecified error".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Oracle error occurred, but error message could not be retrieved from Oracle.".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Data type is not supported."
Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Source [1]]: Opening a rowset for ""MySchema"."MyTable"" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.
```

I did not see any Oracle OLE drivers to select. I considered downloading one (ODAC101040.exe (174MB)) from here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/utilsoft-088126.html

but the download was very large and I already have 2 oracle drivers on my PC that are very large install. I'd hate to download more drivers that I need because they are huge downloads and my company probably would rather me not be a maverick downloader, but if I know what I need instead of trial and error downloading, it'll get done.

When I look on my PC under Startup->All Programs, I see the following menu folders:

```
Oracle - OraClient11g_home1
Oracle - OraClient11g_home1_32but
```

I do not have Admin rights on my PC but I do have elevated rights. When I run the Net Configuration Assistant under the 32 bit folder, I test the connection and it works fine. When I try to run the 64 bit version, nothing comes up.

I only seem to have 1 TNS file on my PC,

c:\windows\tnsnames.ora

this file was manually edited originally. I suspect that it is associated with my 32 bit driver. I expected to find my TNS files under these two folders, but did not find any:

```
C:\Oracle\product\11203_32bit\CLIENT_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\
C:\Oracle\product\11203_62bit\CLIENT_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\
```

Here's my version of the Oracle database that I am trying to connect to:

```
1              Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
2              PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
3              CORE     11.2.0.3.0             Production
4              TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
5              NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
```

What driver should I install to get my SSIS Package to work? I'd prefer to download a compatible (newer?) MS OLE driver but would be willing to install others.

**Added Info:**

My connection string:

Data Source=MyDb.MyCompany.COM;User ID=MyEffinId;Provider=MSDAORA.1;Persist Security Info=True;

Comment: I thought I did so, perhaps I wasn't clear or you aren't familiar with "drag and drop" SSIS packages :-): I created an OLE Source Object and set the connection property to the working Oracle connection object. Clicked the tables drop down and selected the table that Iw anted to pull data from. When I did so, I got that error.

Comment: I added the connection string, if that helps

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the Attunity then Oracle then Microsoft drivers, in that order.  Attunity requires SQL Server Enterprise Edition.

I tend to only install the 32-bit versions and force the packages to run in 32-bit mode to avoid wasting time on setup, config & patching on every developer machine and server, and also avoid the obscure issues between the versions.

The Microsoft driver seems to be the best one for calling Oracle Stored Procedures and passing parameters.

Comment: I don't see the Oracle Driver. That's anotehr issue I am having. I am tempted to download the ODTwithODAC112030.zip and install the Visual Studio Tools, but I am afraid I'll end up with another ORA Home.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331209/i-dont-see-my-oracle-ole-driver-in-ssis-shouldnt-it-be-available