# I don't see my Oracle OLE Driver in SSIS. Shouldn't it be available?

Tags: ssis, oracle11g, sql-server-2012

I don't see my Oracle OLE Driver in SSIS. Shouldn't it be available?

I'd like to use the Oracle OLE Provider that the 32 bit Oracle Configuration Utility says is installed on my laptop:

[image]

In SSIS, I when I go to create an OLE Database COnnection and choose the provder, I don't see the Oracle OLE Provider. 
[image]

Shouldn't it be here to select? What am I missing?

Comment: I think you are looking in the right places. Have you rebooted since installing the Oracle Drivers?  Also double-check you havent got the 32-bit driver installed (directory name means nothing): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188670/how-to-know-installed-oracle-client-is-32-bit-or-64-bit

Comment: I have both the 32 and 64 bit, although I am not sure that my 64 bit driver is workingh ok because teh configuration utility wont come up for teh 64 bit version. I can config my 32 ok. The SSIS packages only run in teh IDE in 32 bit mode, i changed the project option to 32 bit. Regardless of this setting, I do not see the Oracle OLE driver.

Comment: I would uninstall all Oracle drivers and reinstall just the 32 bit one - but more out of hope than certainty. BTW you only spelt "the" correctly once out of 4 times. I hope you approach your SSIS work more carefully or you are just wasting all our time :)